# Gradle asks to put some versions of libraries in 17.0.3

Tags: java, android

Gradle asks to change the library versions to 17.0.3, but this change leads to even more errors

I tried to change all versions, but the errors remain the same. Changed the version of com.google.gms itself: google-services

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.zys:brokenview:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.9.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'net.grandcentrix.tray:tray:0.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.hudomju:swipe-to-dismiss-undo:1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    // Facebook sdk
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[4,5)'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}



ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.3
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.3
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.3
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.3
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.3
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.3
Install Repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hrAW.png)

Comment: Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

Comment: First thing, you should ensure that you're using the same versions of the Android support libraries (for instance, you're using version `28.0.0` of the Android Design/RecyclerView Support library while you're using `26.x.x` for the other Android support libraries). Secondly, you've defined some of the dependencies multiple times (for instance, you've declared the Android RecyclerView Support library 2 times). Lastly, as what @Md.Asaduzzaman has mentioned, make sure that you've declared a reference to the `google()` repo or manually specify the Maven URL if you're using Gradle lower than 4.1.

Comment: i would suggest you to switch to androidx by going to the refactor menu and click migrate to AndroidX